# render math equations in vue

Tags: vue.js, mathjax, katex

Math equations are not rendered the way it should be when fetched from database in vue. Its happening in chrome but working fine in firefox. Like this -

**In chrome:**

[image: chrome photo]

**In firefox:**

[image: firefox photo]

Through some research I found that some third party libraries are there to display math equations correctly like **katex** , **mathjax**.

But how to use them with vue or anyone willing to suggest any other libraries for vue ?

I have gone through the documentation of mathjax. But found nothing helpful for vue.

**My code:**

```
<div
              v-for="(solutions, index) in solutionsList"
              :key="index"
              class="card solutions_section_card"
              style="margin-bottom: 15px"
            >
              <a
                v-on:click="getSolution(solutions.body, solutions.description)"
                class="solutions_section_card_link click_cursor"
                v-html="solutions.body"
              >

              </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: How do you accomplish typesetting at all today? You just import the Mathjax script and throw math expressions on the page? Seems like you're loading expressions dynamically in which case you might have to retypeset the page.

Comment: What is typesetting ?

Comment: The process when MathJax converts your plaintext Latex strings to beautiful math

Comment: Yes. The expressions are dynamic. But how to retypeset page. Please tell in details

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with mathjax

first install it in your project, then copy its directory from node_module to your assets (for better accessibility) and then import one of es5 module to your component like this:

```
import("@/assets/mathjax/es5/tex-chtml-full.js")
```

and one more thing add this code to your watch or mounted hook (after you got your equation from api or something else) :

```
if (solutionsList) {
      if ("MathJax" in window) {
        nextTick(() => {
          window.MathJax.typeset();
        });
      }
    }
```

and then all of your math equation will be in pretty mode in browser